# Automaticly upload to FTPS

Tags: curl, openwrt

How can I upload a file on an `OpenWRT` router to a place using `FTPES`?

I googled `curl`, because it's small enough to install:

```
opkg update
opkg install curl
```

and can handle `FTPES` connections:
http://curl.haxx.se/docs/comparison-table.html

Ok. But heres the problem: i just can't guess out, how could i upload a file.

Can someone point me to a *working, good howto*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I sniffed it with Wireshark and this one uses FTPS:

```
curl --ftp-ssl -T "FILE.TXT" -k -u "MYUSER@MYDOMAIN.COM:MYPASSWORD" "ftp://MYDOMAIN.COM"
```

Comment: I found that it needs to be `MYUSER@MYPASSWORD`, not stating the MYDOMAIN twice.

Answer (score -6):

2 seconds of googling (`ftpes curl upload`) brought up this:

```
http://www.lewisroberts.com/2010/08/06/scripting-ftpes-explicit-tlsssl-with-curl/
```